# How to get an JSON Object based in key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I'm using jsTree and have tree an structured JSON object.

```
[{ 
    "id": 1,
    "text": "TEXT_ONE",
    "children": [
        {        
            "id": 2,
            "text": "TEXT_TWO",
            "children": [
                    {        
                        "id": 3,
                        "text": "TEXT_THREE",
                        "children": [
                        ]
                    },
                    {        
                        "id": 4,
                        "text": "TEXT_FOUR",
                        "children": [
                        ]
                    }
            ]
        },
        {        
            "id": 5,
            "text": "TEXT_FIVE",
            "children": [
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "id": 6,
    "text": "TEXT_SIX",
    "children": [ ]
}]
```

I want to get the the object based on the "id" of the object.

For example if i have a function getIdFromTree(3) it will return me the JSON object as following:

```
{        
    "id": 3,
    "text": "TEXT_THREE",
    "children": []
},
```

How I do that in Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: It is not a jQuery related problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findById (tree, id) {
    var result, i;
    if (tree.id && tree.id === id) {
        result = tree;
    // Revalidate array list
    } else if (tree.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
            result = findById(tree[i], id);
            if (result) {
                break;
            }
        }
    // Check childrens
    } else if (tree.children) {
        result = findById(tree.children, id);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/codescratch/dxL9gpt8/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function getObjById (tree, id) {
  if(tree.id === id) {
    return tree;
  }
  if(tree.children) {
    for(var i = 0, l = tree.children.length; i < l; i++) {
      var returned = getObjById(tree.children[i], id);
      if(returned) {
        // so that the loop doesn't keep running even after you find the obj
        return returned;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Call this as follows

```
getObjById({children: tree}, 3);  // tree is the array object above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  filter Methode off Array

data.filter(function (obj){ obj.id== 3});

Answer (score 1):

try this....   Es6

```
function *getObjectById(data, id) {
  if (!data) return;
  for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
    let val = data[i];
    if (val.id === id) yield val;
    if (val.children) yield *getObjectById(val.children , id);
  }
}
```

now

```
   getObjectById(arrayOfObjects, id).next().value;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with most effective and efficient way..

```
function getObjById (tree, id) {
    for(var i= 0;i<tree.length;i++)
    {
        if(tree[i].id===id)
        {
            return tree[i];
        }
        if(tree[i].children)
        {
            var returned = getObjById(tree[i].children,id);
            if(returned!= undefined)
                 return returned;
        }
    }
};
```

link:

https://jsfiddle.net/aa7zyyof/14/